# Passing Booleans to Chartkick

Tags: javascript, python, flask, chartkick

I'm updating some features for a Flask app which uses the Chartkick module. In particular, some of the charts have a large number of series and it would be convenient to have only a select few visible by default. Since I'm using the Highcharts API, my data is organized as:

```
[{'data': [['value1', 10], ['value2', 20]], 'name': 'series1'},
 {'data': [['value1', 30], ['value2', 40]], 'name': 'series2', 'visible': False}]
```

Based on the console output, it looks like False is throwing an exception after converting my Python dictionary into a JavaScript object. Here's the error for reference:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: False is not defined
    at (index):29

29: new Chartkick.LineChart(document.getElementById("chart-0"), [{'name': 'series1', 'data': [['value1', 10], ['value2', 20]]}, {'visible': False, 'name': 'series2', 'data': [['value1', 30], ['value2', 40]]}], {"library": {}});
```

I had considered using tojson, but Chartkick is invoked with `{% line_chart data %}`. Since `{% line_chart {{ data|tojson }} %}` is not valid syntax, can you pass a variable defined in a script tag to a Jinja statement? What is the correct way to pass Boolean values when using Chartkick?

Comment: Can you please post the traceback or error you are seeing?

Comment: Capital "False" is for python on the server-side.  Javascript/json-- on the client-side which is where your error is happening-- is lowercase "false".